# HttpClient многопоточный парсинг уникальных ссылок

Tags: c#

В продолжение предыдущего вопроса. Описываю более конкретно. Есть локальный сервер, который хранит файлы. Путь к каждому файлу уникален и по ссылке вида:
localhost:8042/instances/UNIQUE_ID я получаю нужный мне JSON ответ. Мне нужно спарсить все файлы как можно быстрее, поэтому я создаю один экземпляр httpclient и делаю параллельные запросы. В результате на каждый такой запрос создается отдельный сокет и их количество в какой-то момент кончается. Вопрос - как подобное решить? Подход через семафор бесполезен, поскольку ссылки уникальны и я не подключаюсь по одному и тому же пути. MaxConnectionsPerServer, также, не подходит по той же самой причине. ConnectionLifeTime попросту не работает, ввиду судя по всему системной нижней границы. Каким образом я могу без костылей в виде реестра снизить время жизни соединения или переиспользовать уже открытое соединение?

> Основной код:

```
ParsingInstance Instances = new();
ParsingSeries Series = new();
ParsingPatients Patients = new();
ParsingStudies Studies = new();
List<string> exceptions = new();
using HttpClient client = new(new SocketsHttpHandler());

var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Instances.DataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Instances"), client, exceptions2),
    Series.DataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Series"), client, exceptions),
    Patients.DataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Patients"), client, exceptions),
    Studies.DataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Studies"), client, exceptions)
};
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

> Класс ParsingPatients (остальные наследуются от него)

```
 public class ParsingPatients
    {
        public string PatientPath { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public MainDicomTags? mainDicomTags { get; set; }
        public class MainDicomTags
        {
            public string? PatientName { get; set; }
            public string? PatientSex { get; set; }
            public string? PatientBirthDate { get; set; }
            public string? PatientID { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task DataGetter(string url, HttpClient Client, List<string> exceptions)
        {
            var DataIDs = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<string>>(url);
            Task[] DataTasks = new Task[DataIDs.Count];
            for (var i = 0; i < DataTasks.Length; i++)
                DataTasks[i] = GetData(i, url, Client, DataIDs, exceptions);
            await Task.WhenAll(DataTasks);
            Console.WriteLine($"Получение данных из: {url} окончено");
        }
        public virtual async Task GetData(int index, string url, HttpClient Client, List<string> obj, List<string> exceptions)
        {
            try
            {
                ParsingPatients? Ppatient = new();
                Ppatient =  await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<ParsingPatients>($"{url}/{obj[index]}");
                Ppatient.PatientPath = $"{url}/{obj[index]}";
                Ppatient = ToString(ref Ppatient);
                Patients patient = new();
                patient = await ConvertData(Ppatient, patient);
                await SQLiteDbContext.AddDataToDb(patient);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { exceptions.Add($"Ошибка:{ex.InnerException.Message}\nошибка в {url}/{obj[index]}"); }
        }
```

Comment: По поводу "спарсить все файлы как можно быстрее" может помочь [это исследование](https://ep2019.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/KNhQYeQ-downloading-a-billion-files-in-python.pdf). Это не совсем то, чего вы просили, но там приводится хороший пример быстрой загрузки огромного количества небольших файлов.

Comment: А зачем здесь вообще HTTP, если это локалхост? Про переиспользование соединений я вам уже кучу раз говорил. Судя по коду вам бесполезно далее что-либо отвечать и что-либо объяснять. На этот вопрос уже был дан ответ, код был написан, но вы его проигнорировали, никаких попыток решить проблему в коде вообще нет.

Comment: @aepot изменений нет в коде, потому что когда они применялись, это либо давало тот же эффект,либо делало только хуже. Вы совершенно не поняли вопрос и меня обвиняете в том,что я не пытался делать. Я пытался. Я поэтому и описал,что те или иные методы результата не дали

Comment: @Стас беглым взглядом посмотрел,что у меня используется судя по всему ровно тот же подход,но либо на питоне метод уже сам по себе переиспользует соединения открытые,либо там количество запросов не достигает границы и попросту с этой проблемой не сталкивались

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, что делать чтобы HttpClient переиспользовал подключения, я уже отвечал, что он без дополнительных усилий будет это делать сам. Вам следует только ограничить количество одновременно работающих запросов. В таком случае он переиспользует уже открытое освободившееся соединение к хосту для последующего запроса. Это происходит автоматически. Если у вас что-то не получилось, надо работать с тем, что именно не получилось, а спрашивать уже отвеченное заново. Я бы мог скопировать код 1 в 1 из прошлого удаленного ответа, но толку? Единственный верный ответ вам не подходит. Мы в тупике.

Comment: _Подход через семафор бесполезен, поскольку ссылки уникальны и я не подключаюсь по одному и тому же пути._ пути или хосту? пусть не имеет значения, хост имеет. По-прежденму держите детали в секрете. У меня прекрасно оно через семафор работает, я по 200 мегабайт данных через пару сотен запросов за считанные секунды из API выкачиваю используя всего одно единственное HTTP/2 соединение. Когда не было HTTP/2, я все равно укладывался в десяток подключений.

Comment: https://makolyte.com/csharp-configuring-how-long-an-httpclient-connection-will-stay-open/ вот еще неплохая статья по конфигурированию `SocketsHttpHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, дубль 2.

Попробуйте ограничить количество одновременно работающих запросов. Это должно смягчить или прекратить эффект истощения сокетов.

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(Environment.ProcessorCount * 2);
private static readonly HttpClient client = new(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All })
{
    DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
};
```

```
public async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string url)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(url);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Ну и вызывать вот так

```
var DataIDs = await GetJsonAsync<List<string>>(url);

patient = await GetJsonAsync<Patients>($"{url}/{obj[index]}");
```

Comment: Попробовал ещё раз. Выяснил,что все же оно работает,но как-то через раз. Видимо тогда все же ошибки таймаута вылетали тоже

Comment: @0_o уменьшите значение в конструкторе семафора, например

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Оно в итоге все равно криво-косо, но порой доходит до лимита.  Но там надо довольно долго ждать. Текущего лимита мне хватит